# Make Javascript generated grid cells resize for the users screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple game on Javascript but can't figure out how to make the cells resize dynamically based on the screen size of the user. I only got it to work with giving the cells a 200px size, but obviously it doesn't work on mobile or larger grid sizes. The game asks which size of a game area-grid you would like to generate and then creates it. I would like the grid cells to automatically resize based on how much size they have available. I have hosted the game on this page so you can see how it functions: http://localhost:8383/JWTHarkkaty%C3%B6/index.html

And the css looks like this:

```
.row {

  height: auto;
  width: auto;

}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;


  border: solid darkgray; 
  background-color: darkgray;
  background: no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.div{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.parentButton {
 display:block;
 float:left;
}
body{
 background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
#scoreText{
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And the Javascript part that generates the grid based on user input:

```
function generateGrid(){
    var empty = document.getElementById("container");
    if(empty !== null){

    empty.remove();
    }
   gridSize = parseInt(prompt("Give grid size"));
   var container = document.createElement('div');
   container.id = "container";

   for(var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++){
       var row = document.createElement('div');
       row.className = "row";
       row.id = "row" + i;
       for(var a = 0; a <gridSize; a++){
           var box = document.createElement('div');
            box.className = "box";
            row.appendChild(box);

       }
       container.appendChild(row);
   }
   console.log(container);
   document.getElementById("gameArea").appendChild(container);
}
```

I tried margin:auto but it just rendered the whole grid useless.

Comment: We cannot view a page that you are hosting locally. Please create a [minimal version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue and so that we can help troubleshoot. Perhaps you could use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to create an example.

Comment: sorry my bad, i actually pasted the localhost

Comment: Your localhost link only works on your computer (because it's hosted on your machine).  We cannot view it on any other machine (unless you include a public IP). I would recommend sharing a code example on something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: https://people.uta.fi/~is425305/Peli/ this was the actual link i wanted to paste